# Bridge the gap between theory and practice in Integer Programming

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, reference-request, integer-programming, applications

I've finished Wolsey's book on Integer programming. It's a theoretic book. 
I aim to learn how the ideas presented in the book can be applied to solve **real-world non-academic problems**. 
I am looking for examples (codes, papers, etc.), any resource that can bridge the gap between theory and practice.

Comment: Hi @Best_fit, and welcome to OR.SE. This question is *super* broad -- essentially, "applying Integer Programming" describes the career of thousands of operations researchers. There are many codes, books, papers, etc. that you can look to. Browsing the questions on this site will also give you lots of examples.

Comment: If you can narrow down your question (e.g., request recommendations for a particular type of book or a particular topic) that would help a lot.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Maybe asking for a small project ideas that aim to use different techniques ? Is that less broad ?

Comment: I'd suggest that you take a look at the questions with [tag:reference_request]. e.g. [references on the empirical study on the practice of OR](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/986/references-on-the-empirical-study-on-the-practice-of-or) or [Recommended books/materials for practical applications of Operations Research in industry](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/117/recommended-books-materials-for-practical-applications-of-operations-research-in/1008#1008)

Comment: @Best_fit yes, asking for project ideas would be less broad. Give us some context about what sort of project you are hoping to do, and why. Also please first read these similar questions: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/738/is-my-approach-to-my-internship-project-good-optimal-allocation-of-product-acro and https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/962/machine-learning-and-operations-research-projects.

Comment: or look into [tag:online-resources] tag for finding some source code. e.g. [List of Implementations for common OR problems](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/841/list-of-implementations-for-common-or-problems)

Answer (score 6):

Some of the problems in our repository ([problem definitions](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#examplesOverview), [datasets](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/data)) are based on conversations with real-world business users or end users:

These directly:

- conference scheduling
- flight assignment scheduling
- rocktour
- meetingscheduling
- tennis

Others indirectly, through the academic challenges that defined them (such as pas, nurserostering, course scheduling, etc IIRC)

There are also a bunch that we just invented out of thin air (cloud balancing, dinnerparty, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Some good places code-wise to start would be SCIP, Couenne, and MINOTAUR, because their code is fairly well written. If you're feeling really hardcore you can also try reading BONMIN's code but that's pretty undecipherable.